# ESXi 5.5 remove @vsphere.local from login

Tags: vmware-esxi, vmware-vsphere, vmware-esx

How can I change the vsphere login from administrator@vsphere.local to administrator? I have searched around. Either it cannot be done or it is common knowledge, because I cannot find a solution. The esxi servers are not on a domain and the laptop I use to access the virtual environment is not either. Regardless, the web client also reguires the @vsphere.local as well.

Thanks for any assistance.

I am on 5.5

DM

Comment: did you tried to edit it in vSphere > your server > user & group tab ?

Comment: I'm pretty certain it is required if you don't use your own SSO domain since it is the default SSO domain.

Answer (score 3):

You need to setup the Default SSO Domain. Even if your vCenter isn´t configured to integrate a [Windows Domain](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc782657(v=ws.10).aspx), it will create a local vsphere domain(thus, @vsphere.local).

To supress the domain during login, you can configure the default SSO Login with the following steps:

> **Procedure**
>
> 1 - Log in to the vSphere Web Client as administrator@vsphere.local or as another user with vCenter Single Sign-On administrator privileges.
>
> 2 - Browse to **Administration > Single > Sign-On > Configuration**.
>
> 3 - On the **Identity Sources** tab, select an identity source and click the **Set as Default Domain** icon. In the domain display, the default domain shows (default) in the Domain column.

Related documentation:

- Set the Default Domain for vCenter Single Sign-On - [VMware vSphere 5.5 Documentation](https://pubs.vmware.com/vsphere-55/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.vmware.vsphere.security.doc%2FGUID-11E651EF-4503-43BC-91F1-15502D586DE2.html)